# Get data from the last column with data per row

Tags: r

I have different sequences of events for elements in a spreadsheet. Row to row the number of events differ.
I want to get the last element for each row and put it in another column for each element as in the column "Last"

```
   ev1  ev2  ev3 ev4  Last
A  A1   A2   A3   NA   A3
B  B1   B2   NA   NA   B2
C  C1   C2   C3   C4   C4
D  D1   D2   D3   NA   D3
E  E1   NA   NA   NA   E1
```

If any of the events in each row is = "Delivered" I want to show Delivered instead of the last event.

[image: example of data]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `dplyr::coalesce` on the whole data.frame. But you have to change the order of the columns. The `coalesce` collapses right to left but you want last column (right most). The solution could be:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Last <- coalesce(!!! df[ncol(df):1])
df
#   ev1  ev2  ev3  ev4 Last
# A  A1   A2   A3 <NA>   A3
# B  B1   B2 <NA> <NA>   B2
# C  C1   C2   C3   C4   C4
# D  D1   D2   D3 <NA>   D3
# E  E1 <NA> <NA> <NA>   E1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"ev1  ev2  ev3 ev4  
A    A1   A2   A3   NA
B    B1   B2   NA   NA
C    C1   C2   C3   C4
D    D1   D2   D3   NA
E    E1   NA   NA   NA",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```